# Count the number of times a Group of Values appeared in whole dataset

Tags: r

I need to find how many times a group appeared in the whole dataset & number it alongside. below is the sample data. lets say if Group1 appears for first time then number it as 1 along side similarly if it appears again down the lane then number it as 2 along side & so on... for each group.. please refer to teh sample data & expected output for more clarity.

Sample data:

```
  Group
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group2
Group2
Group2
Group2
Group2
Group2
Group2
Group2
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group2
Group2
Group2
Group2
Group2
Group2
Group2
Group2
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group3
Group3
Group3
Group3
Group3
Group3
Group3
Group3
Group3
Group3
```

Expected Output:

```
   Group    No of times
Group1  1
Group1  1
Group1  1
Group1  1
Group1  1
Group1  1
Group2  1
Group2  1
Group2  1
Group2  1
Group2  1
Group2  1
Group2  1
Group2  1
Group1  2
Group1  2
Group1  2
Group1  2
Group1  2
Group1  2
Group1  2
Group1  2
Group2  2
Group2  2
Group2  2
Group2  2
Group2  2
Group2  2
Group2  2
Group2  2
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group1  3
Group3  1
Group3  1
Group3  1
Group3  1
Group3  1
Group3  1
Group3  1
Group3  1
Group3  1
Group3  1
```

Comment: I need to create a new variable called No of times which will tell me how many times that particular group is appearing in the entire dataset - for example for  Group1 you can see the variable "No of times" showing 1 initially & how it changes to 2 & 3 whenever it shows up next time. Number would change when the another group appears .. Please don't take an aggregated sum of how many times a group appeared...just number it along side. Am I clear..

Comment: @Coolsun do you needs to have a column that points out if it's the first time that appears Group1, the second time that appears Group1... for each group? If so, could you can make the question a bit more clear? The data and expected output were ok (if you intended what I say), but the question, not too much.

Comment: @s_t  its done. please check now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `data.table` `rleid` we create a `new` column giving a different value for every change in `Group` column. We then `group_by` `Group` and for every change in value of `new` we increment the count using `cumsum`.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(new = rleid(Group)) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(no_of_times = cumsum(c(1,diff(new) != 0))) %>%
  select(-new)


#   Group no_of_times
#1  Group1           1
#2  Group1           1
#3  Group1           1
#4  Group1           1
#5  Group1           1
#6  Group1           1
#7  Group2           1
#8  Group2           1
#9  Group2           1
#10 Group2           1
#11 Group2           1
#12 Group2           1
#13 Group2           1
#14 Group2           1
#15 Group1           2
#.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Ronak's answer is great compared to mine, but here is the dplyr/tidyr solution I came up with anyway. The idea is:

1. Number the rows in their original order.
2. Sort the table by Group. The breaks between the clusters of groups will be marked by a sudden jump in row number (4, 5, 6, 15, 16, 17...).
3. Assign a cluster number to the first record in every cluster, and then fill down all of the NAs.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_clustered <- 
    df %>% 
    mutate(rownum = row_number()) %>% 
    arrange(Group) %>% 
    mutate(mark = case_when((rownum - lag(rownum)) == 1 ~ NA, TRUE ~ TRUE)) %>% 
    group_by(Group, mark) %>% 
    mutate(cluster_number = ifelse(mark == TRUE, row_number(), NA)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    fill(cluster_number) %>% 
    arrange(rownum) %>% 
    select(-rownum, -mark)

head(df_clustered, 20)
```

```
#> # A tibble: 20 x 3
#>    Group  Value cluster_number
#>    <chr>  <dbl>          <int>
#>  1 Group1   1                1
#>  2 Group1   2                1
#>  3 Group1   1                1
#>  4 Group1   1.3              1
#>  5 Group1   1.2              1
#>  6 Group1   1                1
#>  7 Group2   7                1
#>  8 Group2   6                1
#>  9 Group2   2                1
#> 10 Group2   1                1
#> 11 Group2  25                1
#> 12 Group2  23                1
#> 13 Group2  24                1
#> 14 Group2  25                1
#> 15 Group1  24                2
#> 16 Group1  23                2
#> 17 Group1  26                2
#> 18 Group1  23                2
#> 19 Group1  17                2
#> 20 Group1  11                2
```

Comment: @DuckPyzamas   I am getting below error when I try to apply this on my data :(      Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure data.table solution. It's based on `rle()` and `rep()`:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                 Group = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1",
                           "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2",
                           "Group2", "Group2", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1",
                           "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group2", "Group2", 
                           "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", 
                           "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1"),
                 Value = c(1, 2, 1, 1.3, 1.2, 1, 7, 6, 2, 1, 25, 23, 24, 25, 24, 23, 26, 23,
                           17, 11, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2.3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 25, 26, 11, 17, 16)
)

lengthEncoding <- rle(DT$Group)
setDT(lengthEncoding)[, group_count := seq_len(.N), by="values"]
DT[, "No of times" := rep(lengthEncoding$group_count, lengthEncoding$lengths)]

print(DT)
```

By the way, this solution is faster than the accepted answer:

**Edit:** Added @chinsoon12's beautiful **one-liner** which deserves the crown!

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                 Group = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1",
                           "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2",
                           "Group2", "Group2", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1",
                           "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group2", "Group2", 
                           "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", 
                           "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1"),
                 Value = c(1, 2, 1, 1.3, 1.2, 1, 7, 6, 2, 1, 25, 23, 24, 25, 24, 23, 26, 23,
                           17, 11, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2.3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 25, 26, 11, 17, 16)
)

DT <- data.table(df)

results <- microbenchmark(
  RonakShah = {
    df %>% 
      mutate(new = rleid(Group)) %>%
      group_by(Group) %>%
      mutate(no_of_times = cumsum(c(1,diff(new) != 0))) %>%
      select(-new)
  },
  ismirsehregal = {
    lengthEncoding <- rle(DT$Group)
    setDT(lengthEncoding)[, group_count := seq_len(.N), by="values"]
    DT[, "No of times" := rep(lengthEncoding$group_count, lengthEncoding$lengths)]
  },
  chinsoon12 = {DT[, numtimes := 1L + c(0L, cumsum(diff(.I) > 1L)), by=.(Group)]}
)

print(results)
plot(results)
```

---

```
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
     RonakShah 3.980914 4.253103 4.898788 4.500009 5.063746 8.021481   100   c
 ismirsehregal 1.494078 1.653283 1.937947 1.828487 2.023246 5.678442   100  b 
    chinsoon12 1.050436 1.239666 1.469426 1.440154 1.646369 2.572168   100 a
```

Comment: another possible `data.table` approach: `DT[, numtimes := 1L + c(0L, cumsum(diff(.I) > 1L)), by=.(Group)]`